# Multiple dates picker that allows for weekday selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'd like to have a datepicker widget that allows for:

- multiple date selection
- weekday selection, i.e. click "monday" in the calendar and have all mondays highlighted.
- unselecting days that have been highlighted by using the weekday selection

I've looked into [Keith Wood's](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#controls) jQuery datepicker and into [MultiDatesPickr](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/), but my JavaScript is very weak and I'm not completely sure of what I have to do next to extend one of these datepickers and implement this kind of functionality.

One other option would be to have standard checkboxes outside the input field, each labeled as a day of the week, and clicking them would highlight the relevant days in the calendar.

Not sure if it's entirely relevant or useful information, but I'm using Django 1.5 as the backend and trying to use this as a custom Admin Form widget.